# How to retrieve an URL inside a HTML page?

Tags: php, regex

I have to retrieve this url from a dirty html page:

......... http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092699/ ......

Obviously url can also be

http://www.imdb.co.uk/title/tt0092699/
http://www.imdb.es/title/tt0092699/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092699
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092699/
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092699

(.domain, http/https or without final slash)

Comment: Do protocol independent URL's matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
preg_match("/https?:\/\/www.imdb\..*?\/title\/tt\d+\/?/", $html, $matches);
```

The url you want will be in `$matches[0]`.

Here's the regex meaning, broken down piece by piece:

- `/` => start regex
- `https?` => literal `http` followed by optional `s`
- `:\/\/www.imdb\.` => literal `://www.imdb.`
- `.*?\/` => matches the shortest string possible before a slash, then a slash; will match the domain end, whatever it is (`com`, `co.uk`, `es`, etc...) and the first slash following it
- `title\/` => literal `title/`
- `tt\d+` => literal `tt` followed by at least one digit (and it's a greedy match, so it will match the most number of consecutive digits it can); will match ids in the format you provided
- `\/?` => optional final `/`
- `/` => end regex

Comment: I suggest being a little more selected with the regexp. `http://www.imdb.spoofeddnsat.example.com/.*` is not a good source of data.  Instead, try `/https?:\/\/www\.imdb\.com?(\.[a-z]{2})?\/.../`.

Comment: hah hah.  I see email "security warnings" like that from my bank all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This would work nicely and it would also match URL's starting with // which is a protocol independent 'scheme'.

```
(https?:|//)[^\s"]+
```

Comment: "//" is not a valid start of a URL.

Comment: Um, yes it is, it's not worth a down vote. http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: Er, StackOverflow won't let me change my vote unless the answer changes.  :(